# Joomla3: manually updating a table in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla, k2

I've got many articles that I need to copy to a joomla+k2 site, I don't want to go to backend and add them one by one, so I am now trying to directly update the databse, partly for learning purpose.

I've created a k2 item and duplicated it until I have enough fake items, this way I just need to update the `title` and `introtext` and ignore other fields, and I've prepared the articles in JSON.

**Now my first question is, where is the best place to put this .PHP file that is going to manipulate the databse?** It has to have the database connection ready and not load the page. Currently I am using a copy of the `index.php` file under ROOT, having commented out `$app->execute();` so it won't actually load the page. Although the database connection is good(I successfully "select" data from the table), it feels very awkward, and also I can't use the developer plugins like "j!dump".

**Secondly and more importantly**, my code doesn't work: I copy the code from [this documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase) and make as little change as I can, but it doesn't work, the `$result` is `true` but the table isn't updated at all. With very little knowledge about joomla coding and database, it is impossible for me to debug it by myself.

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
{
    include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Set profiler start time and memory usage and mark afterLoad in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->setStart($startTime, $startMem)->mark('afterLoad') : null;

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

//mycode
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$fields = array(
    $db->quoteName('title') . ' = ' . $db->quote('asdfasdf')
);

$conditions = array(
    $db->quoteName('id') . ' = 2'
);

$query->update($db->quoteName('#__k2_items'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);
$result = $db->execute();
```

There is no error and `$db->execute()` returns true, please teach me when this happens how to debug?

Comment: Write valid sql query in phpmyadmin then try it in joomla.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to place the file at the same level of the index.php file, but make sure you add some kind of hash to access the file via a browser. For example, the link should be www.yourdomain.com/youfile.php?hash=1234567890

Providing a hash will prevent other people from running your file.

As for your query not working, try the following (there is no need to follow the strict Joomla query methods for a script like this):

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$sql = "Your SQL query";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$db->query();
```